# Art of Electronics - Confused about Zener Diode voltage formula

Tags: diodes, resistance, zener, resistance-measurement

Working through Art of Electronics and the section on Zener diodes confuses me. There's another question about this section on the site ([Art of Electronics - Zener Diode Example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361449/art-of-electronics-zener-diode-example)), but I'm still confused.

So the setup, they give us this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp0b8O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And then they show that the Zener diode behaves like a voltage divider.

\$R_{dyn}\$ is the dynamic resistance of the Zener diode.

$$
I = \frac{V_{in}-V_{out}}{R}  \tag{1}
$$

$$
\Delta I = \frac{\Delta V_{in} - \Delta V{out}}{R}  \tag{2}
$$

$$
\Delta V_{out} = R_{dyn}\,\Delta I  =
 \frac{R_{dyn}}{R} \left( 
   \Delta V_{in} - \Delta V_{out} 
  \right) 
\tag{3}
$$

$$
\Delta V_{out} = \frac {R_{dyn}} {R+R_{dyn}} \Delta V_{in}
\tag{4}
$$

So a few things I'm confused about:

Re. (1) I read in the other thread that this is the current through R. How do we know the voltage is \$V_{in} - V_{out}\$? If we're just concerned about the resistor R don't we want to know what Vin - (whatever voltage is directly after resistor)?

If (2) is still just focused on resistor R, that makes sense to me.

But then (3) comes in with \$(\text{change in }V_{out}) = R_{dyn} \cdot (\text{change in }I)\$. So now we're considering the Zener diode? If that's the case and we're looking at the whole circuit wouldn't \$ (\text{change in }I)\$ be \$\text{change in }V / \left[ R \cdot R_{dyn}  / (R + R_{dyn}) \right] \$ so that we take into account the effect of both resistances?

I'm just confused at what's going on, I can't follow this in a way that makes sense...Can someone please explain?

Comment: "(whatever voltage is directly after resistor)" and "Vout" are the same node in the circuit. They're the same voltage.

Comment: @brhans Oh thanks for this, the book makes no mention of what a node is. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sort of small-signal analysis. For the purpose of the average current through the zener diode we assume that the voltage is (close enough) fixed, so the current is constant. From that we can find the dynamic resistance which is a *linearized* \$\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I}\$. The actual relationship is not at all linear but linearizing it about an operating point allows us to do a simplified analysis with pen and paper rather than resorting to complex models that don't yield intuition into what is going on.

The linear model assumes Rdyn is constant. For a typical Zener diode (eg. 1N4742) Rdyn is 9Ω at 21mA and 700Ω at 0.5mA, so not constant at all. But if we are analyzing the effects of (say) 10% input ripple on the output ripple it's a useful approximation.

So the model we are looking at after this is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNxHm0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here V1 and Vz are both fixed and Delta Vin is an added change in Vin that is centered about zero.

This is a very useful approximation, however if Delta Vin is too large (such that the current through the Zener changes too much) then it will not be accurate.

You will frequently run into this sort of analysis, and it's so common that there is a specific nomenclature- typically lower case letters are used for small signal variables and upper case for the large signal. When you are biasing a transistor for use as an amplifier (intended to be fairly linear) usually you are establishing the operating point, and then you can (often) switch to a small signal analysis using the hybrid-\$\pi\$ model, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I'm still very lost. Can you relate this back to the formula for change in Vout?

When I look at the formula I don't feel like I really understand what the goal is and I can't really follow how some of the formula steps relate to each other.

Comment: Vz is fixed, so is V1, so we just have a simple voltage divider for changes in Vin, so it's just the change in input multiplied by  Rdyn/(R+Rdyn) for *changes* in Vout.  So if Rdyn is 50Ω and R is 1K and there is 1V of ripple in Vin we'll see less than 50mV of ripple in Vout.